# I am Using ListView with Spinner, Whenever I scroll the values are all deleted(Selected Values in Spinner)

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter, android-viewholder

Whenever I add a value to my spinner in List View, Its value is deleted while Scrolling.I have used `ViewHolder` also.But It shows `NullPointerException` while using `ViewHolder`. So help me by seeing the code Below.

Logcat

```
**FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.dellt.quickbill, PID: 19323
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.dellt.quickbill.NightyChoose$CustomAdapter.getView(NightyChoose.java:381)

at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2338)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1273)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16849)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:824)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:500)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16849)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5379)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16849)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5379)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16849)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5379)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16849)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5379)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16849)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5379)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2332)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16849)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2403)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1369)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1640)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6412)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)**
```

----------Program----------

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            int i=0,counter=0;
            for(i=0;i<size.length;i++)
            {
                if(size[i]!=null)
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            return counter;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final TextView t1;
            View v=convertView;
            ViewHolder vh=new ViewHolder();
            v=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customlayout,null);
            if(v==null) {
                t1=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.loca);
                    t1.setText("ID:" + id1[position] + "\nModel: " + size[position] + "\nPrice:" + price[position]);
                    vh.spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                    adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(NightyChoose.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.value));
                    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    vh.spinner1 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
                    adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(NightyChoose.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.less));
                    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    vh.spinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
                    vh.spinner1.setAdapter(adapter2);
                    v.setTag(vh);
            }
            else
            {
               vh=(ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }
            vh.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position1, long id) {

                    if (position1 > 0 && position1 <= 300) {
                        boolean b = check_exist(position);
                        if (b == true) {
                            id2[count[0]] = id1[position];
                            size1[count[0]] = size[position];
                            price1[count[0]] = price[position];
                            quan[count[0]] = String.valueOf(position1);
                            change[count[0]] = false;
                            count[0]++;
                        }
                        if (b == false) {
                            int val = check_exist1(position);
                            quan[val] = String.valueOf(position1);
                        }
                    } else if (position1 == 0) {
                        boolean b = check_exist(position);
                        if (b == true) {

                        }
                        if (b == false) {
                            int val = check_exist1(position);
                            for (int m = val; m < count[0]; m++) {
                                id2[m] = id2[m + 1];
                                size1[m] = size1[m + 1];
                                price1[m] = price1[m + 1];
                                quan[m] = quan[m + 1];
                                change[m] = change[m + 1];
                            }
                            count[0]--;
                        }
                    }
                }

                public boolean check_exist(int position) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < count[0]; i++) {
                        if (id1[position] == id2[i]) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                public int check_exist1(int position) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < count[0]; i++) {
                        if (id1[position] == id2[i]) {
                            return i;
                        }
                    }
                    return i;
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }

            });
            vh.spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position1, long id) {
                    if (!change[position]) {
                        if (position1 >= 1 && position1 < 12) {
                            int k = findarrayvalueIneed(id1[position]);
                            int sum = Integer.parseInt(price1[k]) - (position1);
                            price1[k] = String.valueOf(sum);
                            change[position] = true;
                        }
                    } else if (change[position]) {
                        if (position1 >= 0 && position1 < 12) {
                            int k = findarrayvalueIneed(id1[position]);
                            price1[k] = price[position];
                            int sum = Integer.parseInt(price1[k]) - (position1);
                            price1[k] = String.valueOf(sum);
                        }
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }

                public int findarrayvalueIneed(String j) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < count[0]; i++) {
                        if (id2[i] == j) {
                            return i;
                        }
                    }
                    return 0;
                }
            });
            return v;
        }
    }
    private class ViewHolder{
        Spinner spinner,spinner1;
    }
```